# Node js child process delete multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm trying to set up a node.js child process to delete multiple files via the terminal. This works when deleting one file - but fails when I supply an array of files.

```
const spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;

var toDelete = array.join(' ');

  if (toDelete.length) {    
    spawnSync('rm', ['-rf', toDelete ]);
  }
```

which I thought would end up being sent as **rm -rf data/foo.txt data/bar.txt** (which works on when I type it into the terminal)

...however, I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: You can't be `join`ing the args with '  ' if you're running a child process directly without a shell.

Comment: Ah... so It wont take a string of multiple arguments? I tried it with a straight array (no join) and that didn't work either?

Comment: `array.unshift('-rf'); spawnSync('rm', array); ` should do it.

Comment: Thanks PSKocik - Alex just beat you to it. Your answer also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because it passes your string as a single argument to `rm -rf` like if you were typing:

```
# rm -rf "data/foo.txt data/bar.txt"
```

Since spaces are valid characters for a filename in Unix, it tries to remove a single file named "data/foo.txt data/bar.txt"

So, you should directly pass your array:

```
  if (toDelete.length) {    
    spawnSync('rm', ['-rf'].concat(toDelete));
  }
```

Comment: Fantastic! thanks - and thank you for the explanation. This works perfectly - will accept as soon as the 5 minute delay is up :)